# Entropy of beta-expansion

Tags: ergodic-theory, entropy

We have the transformation $T: [0,1) \rightarrow  [0,1)$ given by $Tx = \beta  x \text{ mod } 1$ with $\beta = \frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}$.
Calculate the entropy $h_{\mu}(T)$ of $T$ wrt the invariant measure $\mu$ given by
\begin{equation}
\mu(A)= \int_A g(x)d\lambda(x),
\end{equation}
with
\begin{align}
g(x) &= \frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10}, \text{    } 0\leq x < \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \\
&=\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10} \text{       ,        } \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \leq x <1
\end{align}

I have to use Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theorem and the fact that if we replace $\mu$ by $\lambda$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty}- \frac{\log\lambda(P_n(x))}{n}=h_{\mu}(T) \text{a.e. with respect to $\lambda$}
\end{equation}

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Try to explain what you did so far, respectively what you are thinking you should do/use to solve this problem. Point out where exactly you are stuck and we will give you some pointers of what to do next.

Comment: Okay, I think I have to find an partition $\alpha$ which generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\cal B$ under action of $T$. Because if $\alpha$ is a generating partition, then I can replace $h(\alpha,T)$ by $h(T)$ in the Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theory. And this $\alpha$ must be a countable partition with $H(\alpha) < \infty$.

Than I can apply the SMB theory: 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} I_{\vee^{n}_{i=0}T^{-i}\alpha}(x) = h(\alpha,T)
\end{equation}

But how do I use the formula for $\mu(A)$ because they intergrate with respect to $\lambda(x)$??

Comment: $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are related by the density $g$ and this density is bounded above and below (away from 0). Hence the measures are absolutely continuous with respect to each other.

Comment: Okay, but how can I this relation in my formula?

Comment: And what does the $\mu$ mean in $h_{/mu}(A)$? This means not with respect to $/mu$ right?

Comment: I tink I have to choose $\alpha$ as ${A_1,A_2}={[0,1/\beta),[1/\beta,1)]$. Do you tink this is a good idea? And how can I plug this in de formula of the Shannon-McMillan-Breimann theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Using beta-expansions, one checks that the transformation $T$ above is equivalent to the Markov shift on the set of all $\{0,1\}$-valued sequences without consecutive 1. The transition matrix is given by $p(0,0)=\beta^{-1}$, $p(0,1)=\beta^{-2}$, $p(1,0)=1$, $p(1,1)=0$, whereas the stationary measure is given by $\pi(0) = \beta^2/(\beta^2+1)$, $\pi(1) = 1/(\beta^2+1)$. Therefore, the entropy is 
$$-\sum_{i,j}\pi(i) p(i,j)\log p(i,j) 
= \frac{\beta^2}{\beta^2+1}(\beta^{-1}\log\beta+2\beta^{-2}\log\beta) + \frac{1}{\beta^2+1} \times 0
= \log\beta,$$
since $\beta^{-1}+2\beta^{-2} = 1 + \beta^{-2}$.